# How to build a VS extension on an Azure DevOps build agent?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

The build fails, because the BuildTools installed on the agent do not have the VS extension targets. I do not want to update the installation manually so the question what can I do?

We have Azure DevOps on-premise, so self hosted agents. The build controllers only have the VS 2017 BuildTools installed.

Comment: Please be explicit on what agent you used, as Microsoft claims completely different that its hosted agents have full VS installed, https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm note sure if this package contains the [VS extension targets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.14.0/) you are looking for.  But by including a reference to it and restoring it you may be able to get the targets onto the agent and get your build working.

Additionally, you can probably [create a package containing the targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) you need with NuGet, publish it to a package repository and then restore that onto your agent during build time.

Comment: The first one is bingo what I needed.